# A silly, but confusing, question about the Inertia coeficient of second law and inertial mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, inertia

My question is about the inertia coefficient on second law.
To be more specific I have doubts on the notation.

1) Some authors show that the force $F$ is proportional to mass $m$ times acceleration $a$:

$F \propto ma$

And,then, they show the existence of the constant $k$ (which is well-known from mathematics).

$F =kma$

If we take the constant $k$ as $1$, then this yields our unit of force.

2)Some authors show that the force $F$ is proportional to acceleration $a$:

$F \propto a$

And,then, they show the existence of the constant $k$:

$F =ka$

But here, the $k$ constant implies on a inertial mass!

I don't know the difference.

---

Following I would like to ask one more thing about the notation and inertial mass. (This is a part of Keith Symon's book called "Mechanics")

Well, Symon writes that the ratio:

$\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}} = k_{12}$

(*note that ,in this notation $\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}} = k_{12}$, he do not speak neither in force, nor mass!)

And then he says that this particular $k_{12}$ is a property of the bodies and,futhermore, he says that $k_{12}$ "is the ratio of weights". Why? 
Why $k_{12}$ is a ratio? How can I realize:

$\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}} = \frac{m_{2}}{m_{1}}$ ?

In "Mechanics" Symon writes ,in a final part of his text, that:

$k_{12}k_{23}k_{31} = 1$

I really don't understand this expression.

Comment: What do you mean by "show"? Newton's laws are established by experiments, they are not the product of mathematical derivation. The constant is merely an artifact of the choice of units. If you measure force in imperial stones, mass in Jupiteroids (fractions of Jupiter's mass) and acceleration in Trouts (the average acceleration of a mid size German trout trying to escape from a predator in May), then the constant is not 1, if you use SI units, then it is. Since units are irrelevant, the first formula that describes the proportionality therefor already contains the relevant physics.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic because it is about your difficulties understanding how different authors explain a concept.  If you compare several books you are bound to find differences and likely to be confused. It is difficult for us to comment without seeing what the books say.  Probably the explanation is within the text.  If not and you are happy with what author A says but confused by author B, then the simple solution is to *ignore author B and learn from author A.*  I think our purpose here is to explain physics, not to explain the differences between different textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To measure anything, first you need a reference. For example, suppose you want to measure length in terms of meter. There is a particular length which is accepted by everyone as a meter. You say something is so many meters long by calculating how many meter-lengths fit into it, i.e. you take a ratio of length to be measured to standard-meter and express the number as so many meters. Same is the case with mass. You take some mass as your standard and then express mass of any other object by taking the ratio of its mass to the standard mass. I just want to make the point that it is the ratio of any two masses that is of significance.

Now how would you find ratio of inertial mass of two bodies? Newton's second law says that if you exert a force on a body then its acceleration is proportional that force, with constant of proportionality being called inertial mass. So if you exert identical force $F$ on both bodies then $F=m_1a_1=m_2a_2$, which gives $\frac{a_1}{a_2}=\frac{m_2}{m_1}\equiv k_{12}$. So what the equation says is that you can measure ratio of two masses by measuring ratio of accelerations the two would have when acted upon by identical force.

Now $k_{12}k_{23}k_{31}=\frac{m_2}{m_1}\frac{m_3}{m_2}\frac{m_1}{m_3}=1$, a trivial result.